# JSON & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Buenas.
Estoy utilizando esta API:
https://api.randomuser.me/

El problema, es que cuando hago un console log, del DATA de este api, este es el esqueleto que tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos estan dentro de "0: Object".

Para poder acceder dentro del codigo, lo he de guardar dentro de una variable:

Por ejemplo:

> `var JsonAPI = res.data.results.0.username` (el que esta como 0 es el que no se que poner.

Creo que me he explicado mal, pero si no se entiende, decidmelo y intento mejorarlo.

Saludos

Comment: Has intentado `res.data.results[0].username` ?

Comment: LOL! GRACIAS!!!!!!!!  jajajajajajaja es eso

Comment: jeje de nada :)

Comment: acepta la respuesta, click en el check verde al costado de las votaciones :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

con `res.data.results[0].username` debe funcionar